# cloning git using maven

Tags: java, git, maven

I have a requirement in which I have to pull all source code from git and later create a jar file using this fetched source code and finally creating a zip folder which will have the jar file and few other folders.

I am completely new to maven, and its my first task please help me with some tips as where I can get started with.

The objective of this requirement is to completely automate process of pulling latest code from git and building into a jar and finally zipping it and again uploading on git.

Comment: What's your enviroment? Do you use Jenkins? Is it one option to combine these programm through commandline? If yes what's your OS?

Comment: yes i will be using jenkins and OS is linux

Comment: Ah great on the page which configures your build job you are able to execute bash scripts. And if I remember right it's possible to execute them pre and post compile process (git pull should be pre compile process and zipping should be past compile process). [Here](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial) are some scripting examples. Sorry can't give you more precise instructions since I don't have a jenkins available here at the moment :(